# Существует ли такое сочетание знаков: "?!." (вопросительный + восклицательный + многоточие, часть которого поглощается предыдущими по типу "?..")?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, многоточие

Точно допустимы сочетания знаков "!..", "?..", "?!", а как насчёт "?!."? Чисто теоретически такая конструкция указывает на эмоциональный вопрос/выкрик, который повисает от недоумения/прерывания, а-ля: "Совсем рихнулся?! Да ты идиот, что ли?!. — И тут получил кулаком в лицо".
Но в правилах не нашёл такого сочетания, да и в целом выглядит перегруженно. Вероятно, вполне хватает существующих сочетаний, но по правилам как, допустимо такое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На большинство ваших вопросов можно легко найти ответ на авторитетных ресурсах, посвящённых русскому языку.
На этот вопрос, к примеру, отвечала [Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=226172).

Comment: Да, доверяю "Грамоте.ру" в подавляющем большинстве случаев, но на конкретные вопросы они порой не отвечают месяцами (приходится их им дублировать почти каждый день)

Comment: @ShiKomarishe Ответы в основном *уже* есть на ресурсах, достаточно их найти, вдумчиво используя поисковик. А отвечать Грамота не любит, увы.